# Missing assembly references after updating

Tags: wpf, vb.net

Today I've updated Visual Studio 2019 to its recent version and upon opening my project I quickly saw that it was giving me assembly reference errors.

I've already restarted my PC, cleaned the solution and built it again and even tried to update to .NET Framework 4.8 (I was using 4.7.2) but it's still not working.

Here's a screenshot of the error and the references: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9HP9.jpg

I really hope you can help me because I've already tried to google the issue and didn't find anything useful.
I'm also relatively new to WPF so excuse me if I'm making a noob type of question.

Also, the project builds without any problems whatsoever.

UPDATE #1: I also tried to create a new project and add a user control and got the same errors (image #4). Maybe it's missing something from the visual studio installer? I'm not sure...

Thanks.

Comment: There's nothing there about missing assembly references.  It's telling you that two types from your own project, i.e. `UserControl1` and `MainWindow`, don't exist.  It seems that the XAML and VB code files have somehow become disconnected.  You need to look at those types.

Comment: Thanks, what you said gave me an idea of what I needed to do. Basically I just created a new project using C# instead of VB. I didn't get those errors so I also created a VB one and boom, there was errors. I don't understand why in VB it doesn't add the name of the project in the x:Class (that was what I was missing). Upon adding the name of the project and the class name, I fixed it. https://imgur.com/a/gSuqbsJ

This is just weird. Also sorry for my english ;)

Comment: It seems now that I'm getting even more errors so that didn't fix anything: https://imgur.com/a/VFaQuLm

Comment: So... bump. can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nobody helped, I created a bug report which is now with a status of "fixed" and implemented in the future release. This was apparently a ghost error. VS Devs also linked me to another post with the same problem:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/663941/wpf-xls0414-%E9%97%AE%E9%A2%98.html

Conclusion: It's now fixed and will be implemented in a future VS release.

Thanks for your time guys.